# Can't add reference from Silverlight app to WCF-service that is hosted by ASP.NET

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf

A "Silverlight-enabled WCF service" was added into existing ASP.NET web-application. On attempt to add reference from the Silverlight Application to the service the following error was received:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How can I add reference?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it the same as [this issue (and solution)](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/18397/61854.aspx)?

Comment: At the moment I don't know what was a reason and simple solution for my problem, but going through listed links I get my solution workable. Thanks!